# filtering data based on rank and conditions

Tags: r

I have some data which looks similar to the following:

```
# A tibble: 2,717 x 6
# Groups:   date [60]
   symbol date       monthly.returns score totals score_rank
   <chr>  <date>               <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>      <int>
 1 GIS    2010-01-29        0.0128   0.436  119.           2
 2 GIS    2010-02-26        0.00982  0.205  120.           1
 3 GIS    2010-03-31       -0.0169   0.549   51.1          3
 4 GIS    2010-04-30        0.0123   0.860   28.0          4
 5 GIS    2010-05-28        0.000984 0.888   91.6          4
 6 GIS    2010-06-30       -0.00267  0.828   15.5          4
 7 GIS    2010-07-30       -0.0297   0.482   81.7          2
 8 GIS    2010-08-31        0.0573   0.408   57.2          3
 9 GIS    2010-09-30        0.0105   0.887   93.3          4
10 GIS    2010-10-29        0.0357   0.111   96.6          1
# ... with 2,707 more rows
```

I have a `score_rank`, what I want to do is whenever the `totals` column is > 100 filter the data in the following way:

1) When the `score_rank` = 1, take the top 5% of observations based on the `score` column

2) When the `score_rank` = 2 or 3, take a random sample of 5% of the observations

3) When the `score_rank` = 4, take the bottom 5% of observations based on the `score` column.

Data:

```
tickers <- c("GIS", "KR", "MKC", "SJM", "EL", "HRL", "HSY", "K", 
             "KMB", "MDLZ", "MNST", "PEP", "PG", "PM", "SYY", "TAP", "TSN", "WBA", "WMT",
             "MMM", "ABMD", "ACN", "AMD", "AES", "AON", "ANTM", "APA", "CSCO", "CMS", "KO", "GRMN", "GPS",
             "JEC", "SJM", "JPM", "JNPR", "KSU", "KEYS", "KIM", "NBL", "NEM", "NWL", "NFLX", "NEE", "NOC", "TMO", "TXN", "TWTR")

library(tidyquant)
data <- tq_get(tickers,
               get = "stock.prices",              # Collect the stock price data from 2010 - 2015
               from = "2010-01-01",
               to = "2015-01-01") %>%
  group_by(symbol) %>%
  tq_transmute(select = adjusted,                 # Convert the data from daily prices to monthly prices
               mutate_fun = periodReturn,
               period = "monthly",
               type = "arithmetic")

data$score <- runif(nrow(data), min = 0, max = 1)
data$totals <- runif(nrow(data), min = 10, max = 150)

data <- data %>%
  group_by(date) %>%
  mutate(
    score_rank = ntile(score, 4)
  )
```

Edit: Added code.

Comment: Apologies, since I didn't make myself clear here. I want to group by `date` - so each month I compute the `score_rank` and I also want to filter the data based on the same grouping. i.e. each month take the top 5% of observations.

Comment: Again correct, I created the `totals` column using: `data$totals <- runif(nrow(data), min = 10, max = 150)`

Comment: Done. The totals is just randomly created here. In the actual data the `totals` represents the number of symbols in each month. In some months I have 20 symbols and in others I have 200 symbols. Its not reaistic to invest in all 200 companies which I why I want to filter some out.

Comment: Looking at it now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one option to `filter`.  Create a `list` of functions (`fs`) for each corresponding 'score_rank', use `map2` to loop over the `list` functions and the corresponding 'score_rank' `list` of `vector`s, `filter` the 'data' where the 'totals' is greater than 100, and the 'score_rank' `%in%` the input from `map2` vector, apply the function on 'score' column to `filter` the sample of rows and bind the subset data with the data `filter`ed where 'totals' is less than or equal to 100

```
library(purrr)
library(dplyr)
fs <- list(as_mapper(~  . >= quantile(., prob = 0.95)), 
       as_mapper(~ row_number() %in% sample(row_number(), round(0.05 * n()) )),
       as_mapper(~  . <= quantile(., prob = 0.05))
       )


map2_df(list(1, c(2, 3), 4), fs, ~          

    data %>%        
        filter(totals > 100, score_rank %in% .x) %>%
        filter(.y(score))

         )%>%   bind_rows(data %>%
                            filter(totals <= 100))
```